# Web Scraper: Error while printing pandas list

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=40.71455000000003&lon=-74.00713999999994#.XxWVcSgzbIU")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-list')
items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

'''



print(items[1].find(class_='period-name').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='short-desc').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='temp').get_text())
'''
#Doing the above with list comprehesion
period_names=[item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
short_descrpition=[item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
temp_names=[item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]

weather_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
    'period':period_names,
    'short_descrpition': short_descrpition,
    'temperature':temp_names,
    }
print(weather_stuff)
```

I'm getting an error for invalid syntax used for print. This is really frustrating as I'm new to webscraping and this for meant for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I see that you are missing the closing round bracket here: `'temperature':temp_names,    }` and also having an unnecessary `,` there.

The following should get rid of `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for `print`.

```py
weather_stuff = pd.DataFrame({
    'period': period_names,
    'short_descrpition': short_descrpition,
    'temperature': temp_names
    })

print(weather_stuff)
```